# Not able to display Applet

Tags: java, applet

I have developed a JSP webapplication with an Applet. I am not able to display the applet from my JSP page.

Below is the code:

```
<applet codebase="http://localhost:8080/av_applet_jsp/applets" code="av_app.class" WIDTH="200" HEIGHT="100">
```

`av_app.class` is located inside `Webcontent/applets/`

Where I am going wrong?

Here is my applet class:

```
public class av_app extends Applet {

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int inset;
        int rectWidth, rectHeight;
        g.setColor(Color.pink);
        g.fillRect(0,0,300,160);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        inset = 0;
        rectWidth = 299;
        rectHeight = 159;
        while (rectWidth >= 0 && rectHeight >= 0) {
            g.drawRect(inset, inset, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            inset += 15;
            rectWidth -= 30;
            rectHeight -= 30;
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to see applet using applet viewer. What I am doing wrong in my JSP page?

When I tried [an example code](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/applet.html) it's working:

```
<applet codebase="http://java.sun.com/applets/NervousText/1.1"
    code="NervousText.class" width=400 height=75>
  <param name="text" value="Welcome to HotJava!">
</applet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a codebase of..

http://localhost:8080/av_applet_jsp/applets

..and code attribute of..

av_app.class

..the JVM will be looking for the class in..

http://localhost:8080/av_applet_jsp/applets/av_app.class

OTOH you state the applet is actually located at..

http://localhost:8080/Webcontent/applets//av_app.class

Either move the class to where the applet is expecting to find it, or change the HTML to look where it is located.

Comment: my class is located at " http://localhost:8080/av_applet_jsp/applets/av_app.class "

Answer (score 1):

problem was i also mentioned package name in the class ,after removing its working fine ,thnkx for the answers guys

common help

"http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/problemsindex.html"

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you browse to `http://localhost:8080/av_applet_jsp/applets`?  Is your class file there?

On another note, it appears that you did not [package your applet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jar/jarGuide.html) as a JAR.  Why not?

Comment: Packaging is not necessary for an applet to function. It's however indeed the recommend way to distribute it whenever you've more than one class.

Comment: @BalusC - I do realize that (dug through and checked), but was curious since it seems to be a standard.

Comment: It was just to avoid OP getting more confused :) Packaging is not necessarily the root cause of his problem.

Comment: yeah class file is present in the location " http://localhost:8080/av_applet_jsp/applets "